# MongoDB-Convert double to string in aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I am trying to convert a double type of value (daily_min) to string. But when I execute the query I get "Unrecognized expression '$toString'" error message.

My query:

```
db.dbname.aggregate([
            { "$group": {
                "_id": "$date",
                "value": { "$min": "$daily_min"},
                }
            },
            { "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "date": "$_id",
                "value" : {"$toString": "$value"},
                }
            },
            { "$sort" : { "value": 1 } },
            { "$limit" : 1 }        
        ])
```

I would like to implement the following conversion:

```
"value" : { "$concat": [ {"$toString":"$value"}," C" ] }
// result: value: "-21.31 C"
```

What could be the issue with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your mongo version

```
"$toString" New in version 4.0.
```